# How to allow cancel to be selected in the Windows File Dialog Box gracefully

Tags: excel, exit, vba

Hello All (experts and those smarter than me),

I am running into an issue where when I hit cancel to the Windows 'File Open' Dialog, it debugs into this line. What I want to do, is I want to add some sort of 'exception', where if I hit Cancel to the 'File Open' Dialog, it does not give me a "Run-time error '1004': and has the option of "End" "Debug" and "Help" but instead, when the user hits cancel, it exits gracefully. This is in VBA. Is this possible? I searched around and wasn't able to find an approach that worked since this is a unique case. I just don't want the 'user' to have to be forced to look at code if they change their mind on the 'Opening' of a file and instead, let them exit gracefully and still be looking at the main excel workbook they originally were.

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strFileToOpen, StartRow:=11, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True, TrailingMinusNumber:=True
```

Comment: If you include the code where you are invoking the File Open dialog, or at least where you are setting `strFileToOpen` based on the results of the dialog, we can recommend some changes.  (I'm not sure **which** File Open dialog you are using - `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` or `Application.GetOpenFilename`, or there may be another one or two)

Comment: In reality it should not matter which file dialog you selected to use as the built in help or online help include an example that shows how to determine if the dialog was cancelled.  Did you look up the relevant information?  If so, what did you not understand?  If you did not look it up, why not?

Answer (score 0):

When you click Cancel, the GetOpenFilename dialogue returns "FALSE".  Try this:

```
Sub CancelFileOpenGracefully()
Dim strFileToOpen As String


    On Error GoTo GracefulExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    'Test if user didn't hit Cancel and run your code
    If strFileToOpen <> "FALSE" Then
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strFileToOpen, StartRow:=11, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=True, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            'Do things
    End If
GracefulExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```